# Searching for a visual block

Tags: search, visual-block

Let say I have the following :

```
....................
.###....#...........
.###....#...........
.###....#...........
............###.....
..........###.......
........###.#.......
..###.....#.....###.
..#.#...........###.
..###...........###.
....................
```

How can I search for the 3x3 squares made of **#** ?
I tried for instance to do a visual block selection of the upper-left 3x3 square made of **#**, copy it (`y`) and then to search (`/`) for what I have yanked (`C-R` `"`) but it doesn't work.

Any idea ?

Comment: Are you trying to teach Vim pattern recognition? If yes: why? If no, what exactly is the underlying problem you're trying to solve? While it can be done, the question is how flexible you want the solution to be.

Comment: Yes, I am working on this exercise : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56701990/bitmap-pattern-recogination
It is not about writing the algorithm in vim, but I just want to be able to search patterns, to try some examples.

Comment: Vim is very strictly line-oriented (which makes sense for a text editor). I'm not aware of a built-in solution for multi-line matches like the ones you ask about. I can only suggest to either search for a plugin that does this or implement the functionality yourself.